# why does express server listens to different port than my react app is on

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, port

My react app runs on default http://localhost:3000/ (which means that app runs on port 3000 as I've figured out), however when I want to get data from client to server, I have to listen to a different port. Here's the code:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const server = express();
    
    const body_parser = require("body-parser");
    const port = 4000;
    
    
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening at ${port}`);
```

When the server listens to port 4000 or any other port except 3000 everything works fine(I can receive and send data) but my code throws error whenever I start listening to 3000. I don't understand how this works, shouldn't I be listening to 3000 to connect to my react app? or am I missing some fundamental knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running each app separately, then you have to run each app on a different port.
You will only need to run the server and listen to the same port if you are serving your front-end app from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! yes I'm running each app separately and now I understand that they need to be run on individual ports but why do I have to specify to listen to  a certain port? Actually I'm kind of confused about what listening to a port accomplishes and why I don't need do specify it in my front-end code.

Comment: @bearthum Listening to a port allows you to... get things from that port. You have to specify a port so you know which port to listen to. If you're not specifying it on the client it means there's a default which happens to align to your configuration.